# Clickable tabs in email markup in GMail

Tags: css, email, gmail

Google recently updated some css features for using in email markup. Is it possible now to use tabs like in this [example](http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-tabs-for-email)  ? Now it's not working for some reason.